# Decent cross-compiler for Mac OS X targets

Tags: c++, macos, windows-xp, cross-compiling

I'm developing an SDL application in C++, and some of my consumers have asked for a version that runs on Mac OS X. I am wondering if anyone knows of a good cross-compiler for Mac OS X targets, and maybe a Mac OS X emulator (maybe a virtual HDD for Virtual Box?) so that I can actually test it myself.The emulator is not 100% necessary though, as it's probably illegal and I can understand if nobody's willing.

I'm using a PC (Windows XP) for my host machine, and I don't have the funding to go and purchase a Mac, sadly.

Comment: For the record, what is your host platform?

Comment: Mac OS applications are delivered as 'bundles' (glorified directories with special entries) so you will need more than a cross-compiler to create a Mac App.

Comment: @trojanfoe Since application bundles are directories with a special structure, there should be no problem in creating an application bundle in any other platform provided the program has been compiled to target Mac OS X.

Comment: @Bavarious: How would you create the .nib and .plist files?

Comment: @trojanfoe Since it’s an SDL application, the OP probably doesn’t need .nib files. As for Info.plist, it can be deployed as an XML file — any text editor suffices.

Comment: Compilation shouldn't be too much of a problem with gcc, but what about the libraries and frameworks? Buy a used Mac, it will cost you less than the time it takes to get cross-building working. You need something to test and debug your application on anyway, unless you're expecting to be cross-platform remote-debugging on your user's machines.

Comment: Alright I'm using a PC (Windows XP) for my host machine, and I don't have the funding to go and purchase a Mac, sadly. I'll just outsource porting then. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest, and most common, solution is the other way: use a Mac platform with Windows installed either as dual boot or in a virtual machine.

That way you will benefit of 100% of both worlds and never be bothered whenever a Mac system update is delivered.

Bonus: You can install Linux as well.

Comment: Yes, even though there ARE ways to compile for OSX on Linux, doing it the other way is so much easier.